# Bootstrap collapsable Navtabs menu items not returning to normal list mode when maximizing the window

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to apply the bootstrap collapsable navbar effect to the navtabs. It is working fine in responsive mode but when comes to desktop mode or maximizing the window from responsive mode, the 'navstack' and 'collapse in' class still applies to the navtabs. This results me to face the bug the list menus displays vertically and taking full width not horizontally.

And also navbar collapse not hiding the navtab smoothly when clicking the nav-toggle. The screenshot of the bug is attached here for easy understanding.

**HTML**

```
<div class="portlet-title tabbable-line" >
<div class="caption" style="padding-left: 10px">
    <h3 class="media-heading" id="doctornamevalue"></h3>
</div>
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#emr_schedule_menu">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
</div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="emr_schedule_menu">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs pull-right">
        <li style="border-bottom: 0px solid #ffffff; display:none;">
            <select class="form-control input-medium" style="width: auto; margin-left: 5px; display: none; margin-right: 150px;" data-placeholder="Choose a Category" id="mypatientlist" onchange="LoadselectedPatient();"></select>
        </li>
        <li class="" id="activeVideo">
            <a href="#tab_5" data-toggle="tab" onclick="TabHide(5);">Live Chat </a>
        </li>
        <li class="" id="activecrosscover">
            <a href="#tab_4" data-toggle="tab" onclick="TabHide(4);">CrossCover  </a>
        </li>
        <li id="activemypatient">
            <a href="#tab_3" data-toggle="tab" onclick="TabHide(3);">MyList  </a>
        </li>
        <li id="activeippatient">
            <a href="#tab_2" data-toggle="tab" onclick="TabHide(2);">InPatient </a>
        </li>
        <li id="activeoppatient">
            <a href="#tab_1" data-toggle="tab" onclick="TabHide(1);">MyPatient</a>
        </li>
        <li class="" id="activeschedule">
            <a href="#tab_0" data-toggle="tab" onclick="TabHide(0);">Schedule </a>
        </li>
         <li class="" id="activehome">
            <a href="#tab_6" data-toggle="tab" onclick="TabHide(6);">Home </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#emr_schedule_menu').on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
    $('.nav-tabs').addClass('nav-stacked').removeClass('pull-right');
});

//Unstack menu when not collapsed
$('#emr_schedule_menu').on('hide.bs.collapse', function() {
    $('.nav-tabs').removeClass('nav-stacked').addClass('pull-right');
});
```

**ScreenShots**

[image]
[image]

Comment: do you have this in your code at the very bottom before the closing  <!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- IE10 viewport bug workaround -->
<script src="js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Yes all are included.